# Error with targeted_entities

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to set targeted_entities param in targeting for the creatives with type 31

```
targeted_entities = [100003297600281, 100000529832243]
```

on  my request I got  an error message fom Graph

```
(#100) Invalid Targeted Entity IDs -- The targeted entity ids are invalid
Why user ID 100003297600281 is invalid? If i send 100000529832243 - all OK
```